# Select column in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

How to select a column with spaces in pandas dataframe and do logical operation. Below is the Code,

```
not_poodle = mpr[['Dog Breed'] != 'Poodle']
```

In the above code I am trying to select a column name  with "Dog Breed' and doing the not equal comparison with Poodle. But it is throwing error

Comment: Use `not_poodle = mpr[mpr['Dog Breed'] != 'Poodle']`

Comment: `df[column_name]` for selection. You cannot separate a df from it's column name when trying to select a column. `mpr[mpr['Dog Breed'] != 'Poodle']` where `mpr['Dog Breed']` is selecting the column, the condition is giving a boolean series, and finally `mpr[some_series_of_bools]` is acting as indexing.